# How do I disinfect Ubuntu that is running a virus?

Tags: root, antivirus, viruses, proc

My 12.04 system has just been infected with a virus and it is self-replicating a load of rubbish directories in the `/proc/` area.

This may crash my computer completely soon. I cannot delete any of this rubbish even as root.

How do I disinfect an Ubuntu system that has a virus running wild as root?

Comment: You may wish to research further on the [`/proc` file system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs), it is not a virus.

Comment: Can you give us a sample listing of this rubbish? Just so we can differentiate it from the standard rubbish in `/proc/`...

Comment: /proc$ dir
1     1599  1969  2067 24    44   805       diskstats      mounts
10    16    1973  2074 2400  46   806       dma      mtrr
1012  1677  1980  2075 245   47   847       dri      net
1015  18    1983  2076 246   48   870       driver      pagetypeinfo
1029  1818  1984  2078 25    482  894       execdomains    partitions
1031  1844  1985  2079 2552  50   902       fb      sched_debug
11    1860  1995  21 2559  6    909       filesystems    schedstat
1128  1871  2   2101 2579  628  973
1129  19    20   2103 2583  632  978 
1133  1900  2001  2122 2590  658  985

Comment: That is some of it. Every folder of which there are now 160 has 40 items or if you check with "properties" 151 items. THey all appear to have exactly the same content which is why it looked like a virus. Yesterday there were only a few of these numbered folders.

Comment: @user133904 - please edit your question with the information - comments is not appropriate for this type of info.

Answer (score 12):

`/proc` is a virtual filesystem; it's supposed to have a whole bunch of stuff in it that cannot even be deleted as root. It contains folders that represent each process that is running in the system, and various other files to provide other information from the kernel. The files in `/proc` don't correspond to anything on the disk; for the most part the action of *deletion* wouldn't make sense; it wouldn't correspond to any specific action that can be taken on the processes and other structures represented.

Here's my, normal `/proc`:

```
ek@Kip:~$ ls -l /proc
total 0
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 02:15 1
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 10
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Apr  1 20:28 10204
dr-xr-xr-x  8 messagebus messagebus          0 Apr  2 09:56 1094
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 1119
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 1120
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 11231
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 1127
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 26 21:29 11396
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 26 21:29 11398
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 26 21:29 11399
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 26 21:29 11400
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 26 21:29 11404
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 26 21:29 11428
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 26 21:29 11436
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 26 21:29 11461
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 26 21:29 11481
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 26 21:29 11489
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 1150
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 26 21:29 11510
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 26 21:29 11518
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 26 21:29 11536
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 1155
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 26 21:29 11550
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 26 21:29 11557
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 26 21:29 11564
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 26 21:29 11609
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 26 21:29 11627
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 26 21:29 11646
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 26 21:30 11688
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 26 21:30 11696
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 1171
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 1172
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 1175
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 26 21:30 11811
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 1183
dr-xr-xr-x  8 avahi      avahi               0 Apr  2 09:56 1184
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 1185
dr-xr-xr-x  8 avahi      avahi               0 Apr  2 09:56 1188
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 1190
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 1191
dr-xr-xr-x  8 daemon     daemon              0 Apr  2 09:56 1192
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 12
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Apr  2 01:25 12174
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 1224
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 1232
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 1248
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 1251
dr-xr-xr-x  8 whoopsie   whoopsie            0 Apr  2 09:56 1272
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 13
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 1314
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 22 07:50 13357
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 13643
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 14
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 1477
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 1495
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 15
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 15968
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 15969
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 15970
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 15971
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 15981
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 15982
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 15983
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 15984
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 16
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Apr  2 03:35 16019
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 1610
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 1660
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 1664
dr-xr-xr-x  8 nobody     dip                 0 Apr  2 09:56 1667
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Apr  2 04:09 16987
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:00 17930
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 18
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:00 18046
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Apr  2 09:01 18098
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:15 18196
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:23 18245
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:23 18287
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 1856
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Apr  2 09:49 18659
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 19
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 10:38 19096
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 10:45 19188
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:00 19262
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 19298
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Apr  2 11:06 19315
dr-xr-xr-x  8 colord     colord              0 Mar 21 06:52 1992
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 2
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 20
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 2006
dr-xr-xr-x  8 rtkit      rtkit               0 Apr  2 09:56 2065
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 21
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ntp        ntp                 0 Mar 21 06:53 2101
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 214
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2161
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2172
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 22
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:55 2215
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2218
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:55 2219
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2230
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2234
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2243
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2249
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 225
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 29 09:39 22514
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2256
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2257
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2258
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2260
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2264
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2268
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2271
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2275
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2278
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2280
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2287
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Mar 21 06:53 2290
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 23
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2303
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2305
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2307
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2311
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2317
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2331
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2335
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2346
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2348
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2357
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2372
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 24
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2425
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Apr  2 01:25 24576
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:53 2461
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 29 13:56 25198
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:54 2528
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:55 2588
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 26
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 2603
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 2679
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 2680
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 27
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 2700
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 2701
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 06:54 2727
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 07:34 27582
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 07:34 27588
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 08:23 27926
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 28
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 09:01 28249
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 29 14:44 28271
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 283
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 284
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 29 15:17 28655
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 28823
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 10:17 28948
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 29
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 10:17 29039
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 26 09:30 29937
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 3
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 30
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 28 10:09 303
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 22 12:37 30649
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 31 17:23 30701
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 29 18:48 30781
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 31
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 32
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Mar 21 07:00 3492
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 374
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 376
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 380
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 40
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 44
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 45
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 6
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 64
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 680
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 687
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 688
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 7
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Apr  1 14:32 7216
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         utmp                0 Apr  1 14:32 7220
dr-xr-xr-x  8 ek         ek                  0 Apr  1 14:32 7221
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 725
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 734
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 757
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 764
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 8
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 814
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 883
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 884
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 09:56 951
dr-xr-xr-x  8 syslog     syslog              0 Apr  2 09:56 987
dr-xr-xr-x  5 root       root                0 Mar 21 06:52 acpi
dr-xr-xr-x  5 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 asound
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 buddyinfo
dr-xr-xr-x  4 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 bus
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 cgroups
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 cmdline
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 consoles
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 cpuinfo
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 crypto
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 devices
dr-xr-xr-x  2 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 device-tree
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 diskstats
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 dma
dr-xr-xr-x  3 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 dri
dr-xr-xr-x  2 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 driver
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 execdomains
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 fb
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 filesystems
dr-xr-xr-x  8 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 fs
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Mar 21 06:53 interrupts
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 iomem
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 ioports
dr-xr-xr-x 28 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 irq
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 kallsyms
-r--------  1 root       root       1065349120 Apr  2 11:06 kcore
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 key-users
-r--------  1 root       root                0 Mar 21 06:52 kmsg
-r--------  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 kpagecount
-r--------  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 kpageflags
-rw-r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 latency_stats
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 loadavg
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 locks
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 mdstat
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 meminfo
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 misc
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 modules
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root       root               11 Apr  2 11:06 mounts -> self/mounts
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 mtd
-rw-r--r--  1 root       root                0 Mar 21 06:52 mtrr
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root       root                8 Apr  2 11:06 net -> self/net
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 pagetypeinfo
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 partitions
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 sched_debug
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 schedstat
dr-xr-xr-x  4 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 scsi
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root       root               64 Mar 24 08:06 self -> 19315
-r--------  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 slabinfo
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 softirqs
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 stat
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Mar 21 06:53 swaps
dr-xr-xr-x  1 root       root                0 Mar 21 02:52 sys
--w-------  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 sysrq-trigger
dr-xr-xr-x  2 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 sysvipc
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 timer_list
-rw-r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 timer_stats
dr-xr-xr-x  4 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 tty
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 uptime
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 version
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 version_signature
-r--------  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 vmallocinfo
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 vmstat
-r--r--r--  1 root       root                0 Apr  2 11:06 zoneinfo
```

Yours should have similar files and directories in it. You'll notice all the folders with numbers as their names. I'm guessing these are what you're calling "rubbish directories." Far from it--each one represents a process currently running on the system; you can even go into it (*if* you own the process or are root) and examine information about the process.

Comment: Just to echo this answer: `/proc/`'s junk is actually working information that the system uses. It's not a virus (though it would still look like this if you did have one) and it's not filling up your disk, it's using [procfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) which is RAM based.